# How to hover and hightlight single line in chart in Altair

Tags: pandas, altair

```
   # Create dropdown selections
    result_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=melted_df['Major region'].unique().tolist(), name="Local authority: ")
    
    result_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Major region'], bind=result_dropdown, name='Area', init={"Major region": "West Midlands", "variable": "Admissions per 100,000 population: women"})
    
        variable_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=melted_df['variable'].unique().tolist(), name="Category: ")
        variable_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['variable'], bind=variable_dropdown, name='Variable: ')
        # Sort the data by 'year' before plotting
        sorted_data = melted_df.sort_values(by='Year')
    
    
        # Create the updated Altair plot
        chart = alt.Chart(sorted_data).mark_line(size=10).encode(
            x='Year:O',
            y=alt.Y('mean(value):Q', title='Selected Value'),
            color='Region:N',
            tooltip=["Region","value", "Year"],
           
        ).interactive().add_selection(
            result_selection
        ).transform_filter(
    result_selection
).add_selection(
    variable_selection
).transform_filter(
    variable_selection
).properties(width=600, height=600)

chart
```

It works, but it is incredibly messy.

How do I switch every line to light grey unless particular line is selected?

I know it is some variant of color = alt.condition(interval, "Tier", alt.value('lightgray'))
).properties(selection = interval)

But not sure how to select a particular line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Tip:

> Altair provides the `bind='legend'` option to facilitate the creation of clickable legends

---

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import yfinance as yf
import altair as alt
yf.pdr_override()
```

```
apple = data.DataReader('AAPL', start='2023-01-01',end='2023-08-23')
tesla = data.DataReader('TSLA', start='2023-01-01',end='2023-08-23')
tsmc = data.DataReader('TSM', start='2023-01-01',end='2023-08-23')
# combine the stock price into one dataframe
stocks = pd.DataFrame({"AAPL": apple["Adj Close"],
                      "TSLA": tesla["Adj Close"],
                      "TSM": tsmc["Adj Close"]})
stocks = stocks.reset_index()
stocks = stocks.melt('Date', var_name='Stock',  value_name='Close')
stocks.head()
>>>
        Date Stock       Close
0 2023-01-03  AAPL  124.538658
1 2023-01-04  AAPL  125.823189
2 2023-01-05  AAPL  124.488876
3 2023-01-06  AAPL  129.069336
4 2023-01-09  AAPL  129.597076
```

Add `selection_point` as **selection**

```
selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['Stock'], bind='legend')
alt.Chart(stocks).mark_line().encode(
    x='Date',
    y='Close',
    color='Stock',
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2))
).add_selection(
    selection
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=400
)
```

**Now you may select object from legends**
[image]
[image]